# Why v-on:change does not work but v-on:input works in vuexy template?

Tags: vue.js, responsive-design, frontend, vuex

In vuexy template why does in v-select v-on:change does not work? Here loadSelectedSourceLeads is returning an array from api and working properly.

```
<b-col cols="2">
          <v-select
            v-model="filterSourceId"
            :options="filterSourceIdOption"
            v-on:change="loadSelectedSourceLeads"
            :reduce="(source) => source.id"
            label="name"
            placeholder="Filter By Source"
          />
</b-col>
<script>
 methods: {
    loadSelectedSourceLeads(a) {
      console.log(a);
    },
}
</script>
```

But When I use v-on:input it works and return the selected source ID.

```
<b-col cols="2">
          <v-select
            v-model="filterSourceId"
            :options="filterSourceIdOption"
            v-on:input="loadSelectedSourceLeads"
            :reduce="(source) => source.id"
            label="name"
            placeholder="Filter By Source"
          />
</b-col>
<script>
 methods: {
    loadSelectedSourceLeads(a) {
      console.log(a);
    },
}
</script>
```

Comment: Because of vuexy internal design

Answer (score 0):

v-model = :value + @input;

This is caused by the implementation of v-select components

The input event should have been triggered internally, but the change event was not triggered

Comment: no thanks ，if you encounter this problem, you can see the internal implementation or documentation. ^_^

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).